# HTML5 input types not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, input

I´m writing an application that deals massively with dates.

So, I´m using the new HTML5 input types for datetime, date, month and week...

Surprisingly I found out this is not working on IE10. I´m using IE version 10.0.9200.

To check this out, please open that page: [Test Link](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/inputs_dates.html)

My typical input type looks like (I´m using Tweeter Bootstrap as well):

```
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dateTime">Período do Relatório</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="reportDate">
                </div>
                <script>
                    var isoString = toLocalIsoString(new Date());
                    document.getElementById("reportDate").value = isoString.substr(0, 10);
                </script>
            </div>
```

And them later I chage the type I need, like:

```
            document.getElementById('reportDate').type = 'week';
```

or

```
            document.getElementById('reportDate').type = 'month';
```

In Chrome it works real nice, opening choose windows for the user to choose the month on week, but in IE I get the following error (translated):

```
0x80070057 - Javascript execution time error. Invalid argument.
```

So, according to this scenario:

a) I´m doing something wrong here ?

b) If not, how can I support these HTML5 in IE10.

c) If in fact this will not work in IE10, what are the alternatives to have a Chrome like behaviour (popup a small windows so that the user chooses the month, date, week, etc.).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) the date-time input types are not supported by IE. A good alternative would be [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Internet Explorer and Firefox do not support it .Check the link here!

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

For the last link check Browser **compatibility** at the end of the page

Answer (score 1):

[According to quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html#t02), the HTML5 advanced form tag features such as dates are not supported very widely.

Answer (score 1):

Date inputs are not supported by majority browsers.

Since you already use Bootstrap in your project I would recommend to use [**bootstrap-datepicker**](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) javascript plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with Angular JS (all cool kids use it). Short term fix is to include a script ref to babel-es6-polyfill in your index.html. Looking at typescript for future implementations.

```
 <script src="node_modules/babel-es6-polyfill/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
```